# Unable to pass data from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having issues passing data from my controller to my view. I have a contenteditable div that I am saving the contents of to my database; I want to then display that in the view.

My controller

```
    {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('view_data');
        $data = array();
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['contactMe'] = $this->input->post('data');

        $this->db->update('content', $data); 

        $results = $this->view_data->loadData();

        $data['contactMeData'] = $results;

        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
    }

}
```

My model

```
<?php

class View_data extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function loadData(){
         $this->db->where('contactMe');
         $query = $this->db->get('content');
         return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

My view

```
<div class="w-100" ondblclick="makeEditable(this)" onblur="makeReadOnly(this)" contenteditable="true" id="contactMe">

        <?php 
          foreach($contactMeData as $contact){
              echo $contact;
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    <button id="editBtn" type="submit" value="">Save changes
    </button>
```

Every time I reload the page it replaces the data already in the database and I just get a blank div. I'm unable to view the data that was in the database to begin with.

Comment: If you aren't routing directly to the controller (i.e., '/edit/') then how are you loading this view? Is there another controller somewhere that loads this view, or do you have a custom route set up?

Comment: I have a basic 'pages' controller which loads the view. My edit controller gets called by my jqeuery, updating the database with the content of the div. The problem with routing directly to it is that every time I reload the page it updates the database with blank data.

Comment: Ah, so in that case, the view is never loaded with data that you set up in your `Edit` controller. You will have to route directly through the `Edit` controller to get your `contactMeData` passed to the view. If the data in your database is getting replaced by just loading that view, then there's probably another issue somewhere else.

Comment: When I route to the edit controller, I just get a blank div. I can still save changes, but those changes immediately get replaced in the database as soon as I reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

try to add parameter on where

```
 $this->db->where('contactMe',$parameter);
```

try to add field name on your view

```
echo $contact['field_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because every time you open the `URL` it updates the `table`, so you need a condition to check if `POST` request was made or not and then update the `column`

```
public function index(){

    if($this->input->post()){  // check for post request

        $data['contactMe'] = $this->input->post('data');

        $this->db->update('content', $data); // try writing db queries in model
    }

    $results = $this->view_data->loadData();

    $data['contactMeData'] = $results;

    $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
}
```

See, if it helps you.